# Откат изменений MySQL с использованием бинарных логов

Tags: mysql, восстановление, откат

По причине глюка не моей базы данных мой срипт сошёл с ума и перезатёр старые данные в уже моей базе данных.

Достаточно свежего бэкапа нет. Зато есть бинарные логи за последние сутки (перезатёртым старым данным, к сожалению, больше суток). Но я так понимаю, бинарные логи хранят только изменения, а старые данные не хранят (хотя внятной матчасти в гугле как-то не нашлось).

Возможно ли в этих условиях восстановить старые данные? Если это всё-таки невозможно, то что, помимо более частых бэкапов, можно сделать, чтобы в будущем данные в случае чего можно было откатить?

Comment: Можно версионировать данные: не обновлять их, а создавать более свежую версию (в целях производительности можно просто создавать таблицу `{tablename}_journal`, в которую дублировать изменения, а в обычной продолжать работать, как ни в чем не бывало).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться бинарными логами их следует пропустить через утилиту `mysqlbinlog`

```
mysqlbinlog binlog.0000003 > binlog3.sql
```

В результате вы получите текстовый MySQL-дамп, который сможете отредактировать, убрав инструкции, которые уже выполнены в вашей резервной копии и инструкции, которые привели к повреждению базы данных. Полученный дамп можно применить к базе данных, например, `dbname`, при помощи утилиты mysql (в базе данных должна быть последняя резервная копия)

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < binlog3.sql
```

Здесь root - имя MySQL-пользователя.